# GitPython - clone_from not working

Tags: python, gitpython

I am facing an issue while cloning a git repo.

I am using function **clone_from** from GitPython library

> from git import Repo
>
> Repo.clone_from("git://github.com/facebook/buck.git", "D:\sample")

I am getting error

> WindowsError: The system cannot find the file specified

Can someone please tell me if this is how to clone a repo using the library?

Comment: how are you running it?

Comment: A little search might be helpful. Is this https://github.com/kennethreitz/legit/issues/148 helping?

Comment: I am running it directly from command line on windows

Answer (score 0):

You might not have `git.ext` in your `PATH`, but that can easily be tested by executing it yourself.
If you see an error, you can either add it to the `PATH`, or set the `GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE`to the executable git-python should execute for git commandline services.